# Implementing hierarchy for Enum members

Tags: python, enums

I would like to establish a hierarchy for the members of my Enum. My (simplified) enum aims at representing different types of food. Of course, everyone knows a burger is "superior" to a pizza and my enum needs to convey this idea:

```
from functools import total_ordering
from enum import IntEnum, unique

@unique
@total_ordering
class FoodType(IntEnum):
    PIZZA = 100
    COOKIE = 200
    STEAK = 300
    BURGER = 400

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) < self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
        return NotImplemented

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) > self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
        return NotImplemented

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) == self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
        return NotImplemented


# Order is important here; smallest entity first
FoodType.FOOD_HIERARCHY = [
    FoodType.COOKIE,
    FoodType.STEAK,
    FoodType.PIZZA,
    FoodType.BURGER,
]
```

Here my food types are arbitrary integers. They need to be integers for reasons outside of the scope of this question. I also can't use the integer values for comparison, nor the order of definition of the food types. That is why I create the hierarchy of `FoodType` outside the enums, and make it an attribute of the Enum after the definition.

I would like to use the positions of the food types (aka indexes) to implement the comparison methods.

However when I run a simple comparison on two of the FoodType mentioned above, I get a recursion error:

```
In [2]: from test import FoodType

In [3]: FoodType.PIZZA < FoodType.BURGER
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1880a19bb0cd> in <module>
----> 1 FoodType.PIZZA < FoodType.BURGER

~/projects/test.py in __lt__(self, other)
     13     def __lt__(self, other):
     14         if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
---> 15             return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) < self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
     16         return NotImplemented
     17

~/projects//test.py in __eq__(self, other)
     23     def __eq__(self, other):
     24         if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
---> 25             return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) == self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
     26         return NotImplemented
     27

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

~/projects/test.py in __eq__(self, other)
     23     def __eq__(self, other):
     24         if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
---> 25             return self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(self) == self.FOOD_HIERARCHY.index(other)
     26         return NotImplemented
     27

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I can't figure out why I get a recursion error. If I use the enum values to build the hierarchy and to look up the indexes, I can make this code work, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Any idea why I get the recursion error and how I could make this code more elegant?

EDIT: as people mentioned in the comments, I do override `__eq__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__`. I wouldn't have done it normally, but in my real life example I have two different hierarchies and some enum members can be in the two hierarchies. So I need to first check the 2 enum members I'm comparing are in the same hierarchy. That said, I can probably use `__super()__`. Thanks for the observation.

EDIT 2:

Base on @Ethan Furman's answer, here is what the final code looks like:

```
from enum import IntEnum, unique


def hierarchy(hierarchy_name, member_names):

    def decorate(enum_cls):

        for name in enum_cls.__members__:
            if not hasattr(enum_cls[name], "ordering"):
                enum_cls[name].ordering = {}

        for i, name in enumerate(member_names.split()):
            # FIXME, check if name in __members__
            # FIXME, shouldn't exist yet, check!
            enum_cls[name].ordering[hierarchy_name] = i

        return enum_cls

    return decorate


@hierarchy("food_hierarchy", "COOKIE STEAK PIZZA BURGER")
@unique
class FoodType(IntEnum):
    PIZZA = 100
    COOKIE = 200
    STEAK = 300
    BURGER = 400

    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            try:
                hierarchy = (self.ordering.keys() & other.ordering.keys()).pop()
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError("uncomparable, hierachies don't overlap")
            return self.ordering[hierarchy] < other.ordering[hierarchy]
        return NotImplemented

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return int(self) == int(other)
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: By the way, why are you defining both `__lt__` and `__gt__` and why `__eq__`? Your definition of equality is equivalent with the built-in one (and if you don't define `__eq__` then you get `__hash__` for free).

Comment: See my edit about why I re-implemented the 3 methods. @MisterMiyagi: not sure I understand. I don't want to compare the values (i.e: 100, 200, 300). I want to define my own custom hierarchy for these enums regardless of the enum values.

Comment: @JPFrancoia Sorry, I misread the trace. The problem is that ``list.index`` searches the list *by element equality*. Your cycle is ``FOOD_HIERARCHY.index -> __eq__ -> FOOD_HIERARCHY.index -> __eq__ -> ...``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion error is not important as your design is flawed:

- `total_ordering` is useless/harmful because `IntEnum` is an `int` and `int`s already have total ordering
- the food items, being `int`s will compare with other `int`s
- not properly comparing with other `int`s will be a hard-to-find bug at some point

Possible solutions:

- add an extra attribute to each member to control food ordering
- (optional) make `FoodType` be a normal `Enum` and add an `__int__` method to easily convert to `int` (and keep `total_ordering`)

The extra attribute can be done in one of two ways:

- defined with the member
- added afterwards

Defined with the member could easily be confusing:

```
class FoodType(IntEnum):
    PIZZA = 100, 3
    COOKIE = 200, 1
    STEAK = 300, 2
    BURGER = 400, 4
```

So I would do it as a decorator

```
@add_order('COOKIE STEAK PIZZA BURGER')
class FoodType(IntEnum):
    PIZZA = 100
    COOKIE = 200
    STEAK = 300
    BURGER = 400
```

If `FoodType` becomes an `Enum` you can still use `total_ordering`, otherwise you should use different methods for comparison; if you don't then you'll have `100` (PIZZA) not `< 101` (a normal `int`) which will be a bug at some point -- an easy example being `FoodType`s and `int`s both being keys in the same `dict()`.

The decorator and `__lt__` would look like:

```
def add_order(enum_cls, member_names):
    for i, name in enumerate(member_names.split()):
        enum_cls[name].order = i

class FoodType(IntEnum):

    ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.order < other.order
        return NotImplemented
```

N.B.  `total_ordering` had a bug regarding `NotImplemented` which was fixed in 3.4, and somewhere in 2.7.  Make sure your version works properly if using 2.7  (or just add the comparison methods yourself).

Comment: Sadly I prefer to not use regular Enums at the moment, even though your idea of implementing the `__int__` method would allow me to do so. I think you forgot a few things in the implementation of the decorator, but it was enough for me to fill in the gaps. I added the final version of the code in my question. The `hierarchy` decorator allows defining several hierarchies for each enum members. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You get a recursion error because in order to determine the `index` the list elements need to compared for equality, which in turn will invoke `__eq__`.

Alternatively you could use a mapping from the enum members to some ordering, e.g.:

```
FoodType.FOOD_HIERARCHIES = [
    {FoodType.COOKIE: 1, FoodType.PIZZA: 2, FoodType.BURGER: 3},
    {FoodType.STEAK: 1, FoodType.BURGER: 2},
]
```

This requires to make the enum [`hashable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c0db88f6abbace79644b2aca2290bf41b1a37174/Lib/enum.py#L641):

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self._name_)
```

This works because the dictionary lookup checks for object identity before considering `__eq__`.

Since `total_ordering` won't replace the methods inherited from the base class, you'd need to override all comparison methods (or inherit from `Enum` instead of `IntEnum`):

```
from enum import IntEnum, unique
import operator


@unique
class FoodType(IntEnum):
    PIZZA = 100
    COOKIE = 200
    STEAK = 300
    BURGER = 400

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._name_)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.lt)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.le)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.gt)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.ge)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.eq)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other, operator.ne)

    def _compare(self, other, op):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            hierarchy = next(h for h in self.FOOD_HIERARCHIES if self in h)
            try:
                return op(hierarchy[self], hierarchy[other])
            except KeyError:
                return False  # or: return NotImplemented
        return NotImplemented


FoodType.FOOD_HIERARCHIES = [
    {FoodType.COOKIE: 1, FoodType.PIZZA: 2, FoodType.BURGER: 3},
    {FoodType.STEAK: 1, FoodType.BURGER: 2},
]

print(FoodType.COOKIE < FoodType.BURGER)  # True
print(FoodType.STEAK > FoodType.BURGER)   # False
print(FoodType.STEAK < FoodType.PIZZA)    # False
```

Comment: I carefully looked at your code and it is probably a good idea, but I ended up using the code from the other answer, it was slightly neater. Nonetheless, thank you for your help.